# javascript confirm not working properly with kendo mobile ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

On Ipad or Iphone when I click on  cancel in confirmation box ,after cancel touching tab or phone screen again prompts that confirmation box .
Here is my code

```
<div data-role="view" id="message" data-title="Message" data-layout="default">
<a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" data-role="button" data-align="right">Close</a>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code

```
  <script>
    function closeModalViewLogin()
    {
    return confirm("Are u sure?")

    }

    </script>
```

Please give some suggession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, unfortunately. Launching browser alert and confirm dialogs messes up the events sequence, resulting in the problem you experience. A common workaround we suggest is to wrap the confirm call in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Phonegap then you can use

```
notification.confirm(....)
```